# What are the rules of the std::cin object in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream, cin, getline

I am writing a small program for my personal use to practice learning C++ and for its functionality, an MLA citation generator (I'm writing a large paper with tens of citations).

For lack of a better way to do it (I don't understand classes or using other .cpp files inside your main, so don't bother telling me, I'll work on that when I have more time), I am writing a function for each type of citation. I might break this down into a function for each reused code if I get more time.

My question is: how does the std::cin object work? I am currently reading in with std::cin >> for the strings I expect to be single words, and getline(std::cin, string) for the strings with spaces. I am not getting the right output, though. I just want to know how std::cin works and why I keep unexpectedly skipping over some some inputs (for instance, it skips over webPage instead of giving me a chance to input into it).

```
void webCit() {
    std::cout << "Leave any unknowns blank.\n";

    std::cout << "Author last name: ";
    std::string lastName;
    std::cin >> lastName;

    if (lastName.size() != 0) {
        lastName = lastName + ", ";
    }


    std::cout << "Author first name: ";
    std::string firstName;
    std::cin >> firstName;

    if (firstName.size() != 0) {
        firstName = firstName + ". ";
    }


    std::cout << "Article title: ";
    std::string articleTitle;
    getline(std::cin, articleTitle);

    if (articleTitle.size() != 0) {
        articleTitle = "\"" + articleTitle + ".\" ";
    }

    std::cout << "Title of web page: ";
    std::string pageTitle;
    std::cin >> pageTitle;

    if (pageTitle.size() != 0) {
        pageTitle = pageTitle + ". ";
    }

    std::cout << "Publication date: ";
    std::string publicationDate;
    getline(std::cin, publicationDate);

    if (publicationDate.size() != 0) {
        publicationDate = publicationDate + ". ";

    }

    std::cout << "Web address: ";
    std::string webAddress;
    getline(std::cin, webAddress);

    webAddress = "<" + webAddress + ">. ";

    std::cout << "Date accessed: ";
    std::string dateAccessed;
    getline(std::cin, dateAccessed);

    if (dateAccessed.size() != 0) {
        dateAccessed = dateAccessed + ". ";
    }

    std::string citation =
        lastName + firstName + articleTitle + pageTitle + publicationDate + webAddress + dateAccessed;

    std::cout << citation; //TEST; remove after
}
```

EDIT: I/O

```
Leave any unknowns blank.
Author last name: Doe
Author first name: John
Article title: Title of web page: title
Publication date: Web address: www.win.com
Date accessed: 4/29/09
Doe, John. Title. <www.win.com>. 4/29/09.
```

As you can see, something is going wrong, because my input is getting skipped over.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with the way you're doing this... Can you copy and paste your interaction with this program, the exact inputs and outputs you have?

Also, I would recommend putting "using namespace std;" at the top (usually right after all your #include's) so that you can just say "cin" and "cout" without having to write std:: over and over. But you don't have to, of course... either way.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: I prefer either `using std::cin; using std::cout; ...`, or putting `using namespace std;` inside the functions that use it, rather than at global level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is happening here is that `std::cin >> firstName;` only reads up to *but not including* the first whitespace character, which includes the newline (or `'\n'`) when you press enter, so when it gets to `getline(std::cin, articleTitle);`, `'\n'` is still the next character in `std::cin`, and `getline()` returns immediately.

```
// cin = "Bloggs\nJoe\nMan of Steel, Woman of Kleenex\n"
std::cin >> lastName;
std::cin >> firstName;
// firstName = "Joe", lastName = "Bloggs", cin = "\nMan of Steel, Woman of Kleenex\n"
getline(std::cin, articleTitle);
// articleTitle = "", cin = "Man of Steel, Woman of Kleenex\n"
```

Adding '`std::cin >> std::ws`' (`ws` meaning `w`hite`s`pace) before your calls to getline() fixes the problem:

```
std::cin >> firstName >> std::ws;
getline(std::cin, articleTitle);
```

But it is easier to see where you missed it if you do it in the argument:

```
std::cin >> firstName;
getline(std::cin >> std::ws, articleTitle);
```

Comment: I was just about to add ws too :P

Comment: That's *not* what happens for multiple cin >>s!

Comment: @Jesse: oh, I see what you mean about 'multiple cin >>s'. It behaves the same, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

When you use the `>>` operator, `cin` reads up until the next whitespace character, but it doesn't process the whitespace. So when you have

```
std::cin >> str1;
std::getline(std::cin, str2);
```

the second call will just process the newline character, and you won't have a chance to type in any input.

Instead, if you're planning to use `getline` after an `operator >>`, you can call `std::cin.ignore()` to eat the newline before you call `getline`.

Edit: it works as you expected when you do

```
std::cin >> str1;
std::cin >> str2;
```

since the second call will ignore all leading whitespace.

Comment: also, note that operator>> and getline both return a boolean-compatible value that is true when it successfully read the input value, false if there was an error, end-of-file, or a formatting failure.

Comment: @Aaron: to be precise, they return the istream, which is convertable to a void* which is convertable to a bool (whew!), which is the value of !is.fail(). That is why `std::cin >> lastName >> firstName;` works.