# How to read user input with adding space or some other character?

Tags: c++, string

I want to read user input, something like here :

```
char *text  = new char[20] ;
cin >> text ;
```

but if the user enters "hello", I want my other empty characters to be filled with space or `-`, something like:

```
"hello------------------------"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no standard and *fast* way to do this. I can think of some options.

---

Suppose we have:

```
char *text  = new char[20];
cin >> text;
```

Note - we ***need*** to know that the capacity is 20! I'd recommend you to use some constant for this, especially if this will be used for other strings, too.

---

Okay, first option - use `std::stringstream`

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << setw( 20 - 1 ) << setfill( '-' ) << text;
//            ^^^^ we need one byte for the '\0' char at the end
ss >> text;
```

But this is rather slow.

---

Fill the chars by hand:

```
int length = strlen( text );
for( int i = length; i < 20 - 1; ++i ) // again - "20-1" - '\0'
{
    text[ i ] = '-';
}
text[ 20 - 1 ] = '\0'; // don't forget to NULL-terminate the string
```

---

And ***the best way***, according to me - get rid of these `char*` things (you have tagged the question as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ) and just use `std::string`.

```
std::string sText;
std::cin >> sText;
sText.resize( 20, '-' ); // NOTE - no need to NULL-terminate anything
```

***Voilà!*** (:

This way is much more clear and you don't need to carry about using `delete[] text;` at the end (which is not that trivial sometimes, especially in case of some exception before `delete[]` - this will give you 100% memory leak. Of course, you can always use smart pointers.. but smart pointers for this?! :)  )

---

Of course, you can write `19` instead of `20-1`, I just wanted to "highlight" the `-1`, in case that you use some constant.

Comment: If you wanted to highlight the `-1`, why not just use a constant instead of `20`? :) Magical numbers ftl.

Comment: Because if this size will not be used anymore, there's no need to add constant for 2-3 lines of code (which _are_ one after the other). Or at least, I wouldn't. Note that I already advised @Ata to use constant in the other case.

Answer (score 2):

None of you said anything about the **null terminator character** - '\0'. It is really important when working with strings in C/C++. For example, if you want your text to be 20 symbols long, you should allocate memory for 21 characters. This is just for information for **Ata**. And the answer to your question is:

```
char *text = new char[21];
//start initialization
for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
    text[i] = '-';
}
text[20] = '\0';
//end initialization
cout << "Your input: " << endl;
cin >> text;//get the user input
text[strlen(text)]='-';//change the automatically added '\0' with '-'
cout << text << endl;
```

Have in mind that you should also check if the user hasn't entered something longer than the memory you've allocated.

---

EDIT: Well, **Kiril** was faster (and more precise) than me. :)

Comment: Are you sure, that `std::cin` _will not_ touch the rest of the chars? I thought about this option at the beginning, but I was not sure if the standard guarantees the behavior of `std::cin` in this case.

Comment: According to this [statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805403/what-are-the-rules-of-the-stdcin-object-in-c) it will read until the first white space character, so I think it'll be OK. But your question is reasonable.

Comment: It's interesting if this is guaranteed by the standard :? But nice reference. +1 from me :) By the way, a little off-topic - what's you DSLR :D

Comment: Nikon D60. I want to move to a full frame Nikon, but it will happen in the near future. :) If you're interested, I've posted a few pictures on Flickr (and try to continue, when I have time which is rarely).

Comment: Nice (y) . I'm planning to buy D5100 soon (probably next month). Anyway, I was just curious (:

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways. For example, suppose you have a string full of 19 "-": (note that you define the array with 20, you can only get 19 real characters plus the final `\0`:

```
const char* dashes = "--------------------";
```

Then you read the string as you write:

```
char *text  = new char[20] ;
cin >> text ;
```

and then you can use `strcat` to copy the rest of the characters, using `strlen` to determine the length of the read string:

```
strcat(text, dashes + strlen(text));
```

This will append the resting `19 - length of the text` into the text. Note that I add that particular quantity to the `dashes` pointer.

Finally, `>>` will only read one word. To read the complete line of input you have to use  `getline`.

Comment: -1: this makes a needless dynamic allocation and the pointer arithmetic relies on a somewhat tricky idiom. It would be simpler to just copy the dashes into the buffer and then read over the first few.

Comment: @Karl: You're right about the needless dynamic allocation, but this was the original code. Just wrote how to complete it. Tricky idiom on pointers? I don't think adding a pointer a value is so tricky at all. Copying the buffer first also doesn't work because the cin puts a final `'\0'` at the end on the user input that you have to remove (and *that* would be tricky).