# ' ' seems to be treated as '\0'?

Tags: c++

## Code

I created the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(char v[])
{
    for(char* p = v; *p != 0; p++)
    {
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << int(' ') << std::endl;
    char c[256];
    std::cin >> c;
    f(c);
    return 0;
}
```

## Compiler

I compiled with GNU GCC Compiler in Code::Blocks with the -std=c++0x flag (with no warnings).

## Problem

The problem I have is that if I enter a string containing one or more spaces (i.e. "one and two") then only the letters prior to the first space are printed (i.e. 'o', 'n', 'e').

## What I've tried

The only thing that sprung to mind was to do a quick reality check. I added the line:

```
std::cout << "Val: " << int(' ') << std::endl;
```

and, as expected, the value printed *isn't* 0 (because, obviously, it's not the null '\0' character)...

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Is it the case that the line:

```
std::cin >> c;
```

uses ' ' as some sort of termination character?

Thanks.

Comment: look at this - the first answer is the one relevent to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805403/what-are-the-rules-of-the-stdcin-object-in-c

Comment: `char c[256];` is a massive security problem; use a `std::string`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain why is it a massive security problem? I think I remember reading something about it, but I can't for the life of me remember what it was.

Comment: Google "Buffer Overflow".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::cin >> c;
```

will only read one word delimited by whitespace. That's the functionality for all the `>>` operators.

If you want to read a whole line, use the `getline` function instead.

Comment: I thought this might have been the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Stream operators `>>` are *formatted input*, which uses whitespace as field separators. If you want to retain whitespace in your input, use `std::getline()` or the stream member function `read()`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm afraid as Bo Persson answered ~30 secs before you, I'll probably choose his answer. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @BertieWheen Fine with me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try `getline` to input your sentence, space is used as a delimiter between inputs by `cin>>`.