# Paste multiple commands to PuTTY - process serially?

Tags: putty

I have about 3000 individual commands that I need to execute on a system via [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY).  I am doing this by copying ~100 of the commands and pasting them into a PuTTY SSH session.  It works, however the issue is that PuTTY does not process them serially and the output gets garbled.

Is there a way to make PuTTY process each command, wait for a return and then process the next?  The Windows command prompt does this and I'm thinking there is a way to do so with PuTTY.

Yes, I know I could put this in a [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script, but due to circumstance outside my control, this has to be done using SSH and in a manner that can be monitored as we go and logged.

Answer (score 9):

I do this all the time.  Put your commands in a `(` `)` block, which will run it as a subshell, perfectly everything within serially.  I'm running Windows PuTTY and connecting to Linux and [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX) servers.  Try it.

```
(
Command1
Command2
Command3
)
```

In practice, I might have a huge load of many 100s of statements I want to run, in [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) or whatever.  So I copy them to clipboard, and then in PuTTY:

```
(
 paste in your wad here
)
```

If you want to log the output from each of your statements individually, you might do something like this:

```
(
Command1 > /home/jon/command1output.txt
Command2 > /home/jon/command2output.txt
Command3 > /home/jon/command3output.txt
)
```

Or if you just want one big stream of output, you could interleave separators for easier reading later:

```
(
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
echo "[`date`]  Now running Command1 ..."
Command1
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
echo "[`date`]  Now running Command2 ..."
Command2
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
echo "[`date`]  Now running Command3 ..."
Command3
)
```

Another variation using an inline function.  All paste-able into PuTTY, with perfect serial running, logging as command1:output1,command2:output2,... , and capable of driving SQL*Plus.

```
(
  function geniusMagic() {
    echo " "
    echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    date
    echo "RUNNING COMMAND:"
    echo " "
    echo "$*"
    echo " "
    echo "OUTPUT:"
    echo " "
    sh -c "$*"
  }

  geniusMagic df -m /home
  geniusMagic 'printf $RANDOM | sed "s/0//g"'
  geniusMagic 'echo "select count(*)
                     FROM all_tables;
                 " | sqlplus -s scott/tiger'
)
```

Sample output:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Wed Jun 25 17:41:19 EDT 2014
RUNNING COMMAND:

df -m /home

OUTPUT:

Filesystem    MB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd1        1024.00    508.49   51%     3164     3% /home

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Wed Jun 25 17:41:19 EDT 2014
RUNNING COMMAND:

printf $RANDOM | sed "s/0//g"

OUTPUT:

2767
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Wed Jun 25 17:41:19 EDT 2014
RUNNING COMMAND:

echo "select count(*)
                     FROM all_tables;
                 " | sqlplus -s scott/tiger

OUTPUT:


  COUNT(*)
----------
        48
```

Comment: This is the closest answer yet, but it's still not nearly as convenient as simply pasting into a windows command prompt.  For example, this won't work when using SQL*Plus in Putty.  Also, it would be nicer to see "command:result,command:result", instead of "command,command:result,result".

Comment: added EDIT2 above to give you command:result pairs and seems to work with SQL*Plus.  Not sure about your exact Oracle layout, such as is the Oracle database on the same server that you're SSH into?

Comment: This answer didn't quit help me with my original problem so I didn't award the original bounty.  But it just helped me solve a different problem, so I'll give you a bounty this time (in 23 hours, when I'm allowed to award it).

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea here: PuTTY comes with a command-line tool called [Plink](http://tartarus.org/%7Esimon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink). You could write a script on your Windows machine that creates a connection to the remote server with Plink, and then parses your list of commands one at a time and sends them.

This should look exactly the same to the remote server (which I assume is what's doing the logging), while letting you have a bit more control than copy-pasting blocks of commands.

Comment: The remote server is not doing the logging, unfortunately.  Plus, what I need to capture is the return text from each command.

Comment: Well, logging on the local machine should still see an SSH connection. Plink will definitely allow you to capture the servers response to the commands you're running.

Comment: So close, but plink has an issue in that it will not do any Putty-style logging, even if logging is enabled in saved session.  I can redirect the output to a log file (i.e. >>c:\temp\log.txt) but errors returned by the remote server do not show up in the log, only success messages.

Comment: That being the case you could go the full route and install CYGWIN, this will give you a normal bash shell on windows and the real SSH client (www.cygwin.com). Alternatively, it may be easier to quickly write a script to do this with a language you are familiar with (python, perl etc)

Comment: Ended up just creating a shell script and getting access to BASH on the remote server.  Logging still didn't work quite like I needed, but  we made it work.  Thanks so much for the assistance.

Comment: The error messages probably go to cerr instead of cout.   Consider cmd >>file.txt 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you could not use [Plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html), but you could make a batch file with [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B).

```
plink <hostname> -l <login_name> -pw <password> <command 1>
plink <hostname> -l <login_name> -pw <password> <command 2>
plink <hostname> -l <login_name> -pw <password> <command 3>
...
plink <hostname> -l <login_name> -pw <password> <command 3000>
```

Run the batch file:

```
filename.bat > log.txt 2>&1
```

[Batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php):

[Display & Redirect Output](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php):

Comment: valid answer but with the drawback of creating 3000 connections instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer you are looking for is [here](http://pgmacros.invisionzone.com/topic/1811-waiting-for-the-prompt-in-putty/).

Here a copy of the answer I think may be interesting for you :

```
   // Wait for backup setting prompt 
    Repeat Until %D1% = 1
      Activate Window: "DAYMISYS1.qdx.com - PuTTY"
      Mouse Move Window 12, 11                        <-------  Moves mouse to upper left corner to activate menu options
      Mouse Right Button Click
      Delay 0.1 Seconds
      Text Type: o                                    <-------  Activates Copy All to Clipboard command   
      Delay 0.2 Seconds
      If Clipboard Contains "or select a number to change a setting:"      <-------  Look for text of prompt that I am waiting for
      Repeat Exit                                     <-------  If found, exit loop and continue macro
      End If
      Delay 1 Seconds                                 <-------  If prompt is not found, continue loop
    Repeat End
```

Comment: This may be helpful to some but buying and installing proprietary software will not work for most people.

Answer (score -1):

In the PuTTY installation I have, I just paste into it and it works.

- Open [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad)
- Type out your list of commands
- Highlight Notepad
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (or right click, copy)

Click on your PuTTY window.
Right-click once, into where you type your commands.

You should see all of the commands inserted into your entry box.

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note: I used this to enter multiple lines into [`cin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805403/what-are-the-rules-of-the-stdcin-object-in-c) prompts from a C++ program compiled on Linux. I don't know if it will work directly into the terminal.